# Find the intersection point between a line and a generated canvas square

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, jstilemap

I have a program that draws a tilemap, and there is a player that can move around and collide with the tiles, my end goal is to make a raycaster, which will make a pseudo-3d rendering of a 2d tilemap, in order to do this, I will need to cast a ray which will intersect with a wall, I know how to cast a ray, but I have no clue where to start with the intersection implementation, if anyone has any tips, or knows how to do this, can you please help, here is my code.

```js
c = document.getElementById("c");
w = c.width;
h = c.height;
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var tilesize = 50;

var player = {
  x: 80,
  y: 80,
  size: 10,
  speed: 1,
  dir: 0,
  rot: 0,
  rotSpeed: 0.02,
  rotDir: 0,
};

var map = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];

function keydown(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 87:
      player.dir = 1;
      break;
    case 83:
      player.dir = -1;
      break;
    case 68:
      player.rotDir = -1;
      break;
    case 65:
      player.rotDir = 1;
      break;
  }
}
function keyup(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 87:
      player.dir = 0;
      break;
    case 83:
      player.dir = 0;
      break;
    case 68:
      player.rotDir = 0;
      break;
    case 65:
      player.rotDir = 0;
      break;
  }
}

var gameloop = setInterval(function () {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  //move
  rotstep = player.rotSpeed * player.rotDir;
  movestep = player.speed * player.dir;
  player.rot += rotstep;
  newY = player.y - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
  newX = player.x - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;

  leftbY = player.y - 10 - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
  leftbX = player.x - 10 - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;
  rightbY = player.y + 10 - Math.cos(player.rot) * movestep;
  rightbX = player.x + 10 - Math.sin(player.rot) * movestep;
  //borders
  var leftcol = Math.floor(leftbX / tilesize);
  var leftrow = Math.floor(leftbY / tilesize);
  var rightcol = Math.floor(rightbX / tilesize);
  var rightrow = Math.floor(rightbY / tilesize);
  if (map[rightcol][rightrow] == 0 && map[leftcol][leftrow] == 0) {
    player.y = newY;
    player.x = newX;
  }

  //map
  for (y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = ["white", "black"][map[y][x]];
      ctx.fillRect(x * tilesize, y * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
    }
  }
  //player
  markerY = player.y - Math.cos(player.rot) * 30;
  markerX = player.x - Math.sin(player.rot) * 30;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(
    player.x,
    player.y,
    player.size,
    player.size,
    player.rot * (Math.PI / 180),
    0,
    2 * Math.PI
  );
  ctx.fill();
  //marker
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(player.x, player.y);
  ctx.lineTo(markerX, markerY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "Blue";
  ctx.stroke();
}, 1000 / 30);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  keydown(event);
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  keyup(event);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas height="500px" id="c" width="500px"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```